# Meteor.js - Publish function not working: Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

I am having some trouble making the publish function work with Meteor. The code I am using is as follows:

```
Meteor.publish "adminArea", () ->
    Meteor.users.find({
        admin: true 
    }, {
        fields: {
            permissions: 1
        }   
    })
```

and I am subscribing with:

```
Meteor.subscribe "adminArea"
```

This doesn't work though, when I run `Meteor.user()` in the console it just returns the default options.

If I run `db.users.find({"admin": "true"})` in Mongo the correct information is returned.

The annoying thing is, this used to work perfectly until I reset my database with `Meteor reset`. Would this be messing it up or does anyone know what I am doing wrong now?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now fixed this issue and it was complete error on my part. I had forgot to add the permissions field to the user in the database so when it ran the query, it would find `admin: true` but then be unable to return the permissions field because it didn't exist.

So note to self: Always add the necessary fields to the user.

Oops!

Thanks